# How do I make a filtered search with multiple fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is what I currently have in my `Index.cs`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication7.Models.vwtest21>
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search By:</b>  @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "PROGCD", true) <text>PROGCD</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Date") <text>DOCRECDT</text><br />
    @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
} 
</p>
```

I want to convert it from a `RadioButton` to a two field filtered search for `PROGCD` and `DOCRECDT` with one submit button. Below is my `HomeController` which I have no idea how to convert into if I change it into the filtered search.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ProjectDBContext db = new ProjectDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {


        if (searchBy == "Date")    //searchBy == "PROGCD")
        {
            return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.DOC_REC_DT1 == search).ToList()); 
        }
        else
        {
             return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.PROG_CD == search).ToList());        
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your view to use textboxes rather than radio buttons.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication7.Models.vwtest21>
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search By:</b>  
    @Html.TextBox("progcd") <text>PROGCD</text>
    @Html.TextBox("docrecdt") <text>DOCRECDT</text>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
} 
</p>
```

Then change your controller to filter by the new textboxes.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ProjectDBContext db = new ProjectDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index(string progcd, string docrecdt)
    {
        return View(db.vwtest21.Where(x => x.DOC_REC_DT1 == docrecdt && x.PROG_CD == progcd).ToList());
    }
}
```

The AND condition (**&&**) means that only records that meet both search filters will be returned.  You may wish to change it to an OR condition (**||**) if you want to return records that meet either search condition.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for!